# Set unique heights to multiple iFrames based on content heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, height

**I have multiple iframes on a single page.** The frame's source is my own domain. 
I want to calculate and set iframe heights on all iframes on the page.

My code currently sets all iframe heights to the same height, from one of the iframes:

```
function iframeSize(){

$("IFRAME_CLASS",parent.document).each(function() {
                var frameHeight = $("body").outerHeight();
                $(this).height(frameHeight);
            }); 

}
```

I'm having a lot of trouble and appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to iterate through each iframe with class `IFRAME_CLASS`, you need to perform a `class(.)` selector on each element and set the height.

```
function iframeSize(){

$(".IFRAME_CLASS").each(function() {
                var frameHeight = $("body").outerHeight();
                $(this).css("height",frameHeight);
 }); 

}
iframeSize();
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/2ass96kf/3/

Comment: thanks. I had tried this with no luck. Then I realized my error: my script was inside the iframe.php template, which ran each time an iframe was on the page, which royally screwed up my stuff. I took the script out of the iframe template and it's working great now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sure. Glad I could help :)